# Scrollable parent Controll with overflowing children to display tooltip in table

Tags: html, css

I have a Table, which is programmatically created in c# (irrelevant). In some cases it is too wide for my page so the table parent Panel is given

```
overflow-y: hidden
```

While this works fine and the scroll bar is OK, I also have some custom tooltips inside my Table which then stop working due to the overflow and can't escape the parent borders.

Hence I end up with a much more complicated version of this: https://jsfiddle.net/kh7m6wdt/8/

While my desired end goal is this https://jsfiddle.net/kh7m6wdt/6/

Note that Line 6

```
<div style="overflow-y: hidden;">
```

from the first example is removed in the second.

How can I have both scrollable parent Control AND visible tooltip ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your Line 6 to this :-

```
<div style="overflow-y:no-content;">
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the message through. I have a lot of cells that need to be scrollable like in the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kh7m6wdt/8/ Apologies

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong. I tried all. It is not possible to have the cells scrollable and display that tooltip text.

Comment: I was afraid of this :(